# SQL query not executing as whole

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a query that should add Primary Key to the Id field:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
              WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CAL')
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CAL$01 ON dbo.CAL;

    ALTER TABLE BTS.dbo.CAL
    ALTER COLUMN Intern INT NOT NULL;

    ALTER TABLE BTS.dbo.CAL
        ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CAL_Intern PRIMARY KEY (Intern);

    CREATE INDEX CAL$01
    ON CAL (Intern);
END
```

The problem is that when I chose all this code and execute (`F5`), I get this error:

[image]

Whereas when I'm choosing every statement one by one it works as expected:

[image]

I am sure that the `IF` works as expected

I tried to use `GO` between statements, it's not allowed.

I should execute this code on a large number of tables

Maybe I don't know something about how SQL Server Management Studio executes statements

Comment: It not MAnagement Studio executes statements, it's DB engine.

Comment: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS came in with sqlserver 2016 - what version are you on?

Comment: I got the last version of Management Studio, I installed it not so long ago

Comment: SSMS and SQL Server are not the same thing, @ValeriuSeremet. The version of SSMS and the version of SQL Server are often unrelated. SSMS 2018, for example, supports SQL Server 2008-2019 (that's 7 different versions of SQL Server).

Comment: SQL Server version: 15.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before a query is run it is parsed. This is why what you're doing is failing. SQL server is checking the details of the `Intern` before the script is run. At the point you start to try to run the script, `Intern` in the table `BTS.dbo.CAL` is `NULL`able, and so the script fails.

You can get around this by running the statement to create the primary key cosntraint in a separate scope:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CAL'
)
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CAL$01 ON dbo.CAL;

    ALTER TABLE
      BTS.dbo.CAL
    ALTER COLUMN
      Intern
        INT NOT NULL;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE BTS.dbo.CAL ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CAL_Intern PRIMARY KEY (Intern);';

    CREATE INDEX [CAL$01]
    ON CAL (Intern);
END'
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though question is answer, I just wanted to add one more option.

You can separate statments into two separate batches, so that your change is available to the subsequent batch

```sql
CREATE TABLE #test(a int null);

-- DDL Changes
if exists(SELECT 1)
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE #test ALTER COLUMN a int not null;

END
GO

-- Index changes
if exists(SELECT 1)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE #test ADD CONSTRAINT PK_test PRIMARY KEY(a)
END
GO
```